# Mathematica permutes indices when reading Matlab files

Tags: matlab

I wrote the following `Matlab` script:

```
A=reshape(1:(3*4*5),[3,4,5]);
size(A)
save('A.mat','A');

B=reshape(1:(7*8),[7,8]);
size(B)
save('B.mat','B');

C=reshape(1:(2*3*4*5),[2,3,4,5]);
size(C)
save('C.mat','C');
```

and it ouput

```
ans =
     3     4     5
ans =
     7     8
ans =
     2     3     4     5
```

which shows that indices go increasing.

Then I read these tensors with `Mathematica`:

```
In[20]:= mat = Import["A.mat", "LabeledData"];
In[15]:= Dimensions["A" /. mat]
Out[15]= {5, 3, 4}
In[21]:= mat = Import["B.mat", "LabeledData"];
In[17]:= Dimensions["B" /. mat]
Out[17]= {7, 8}
In[22]:= mat = Import["C.mat", "LabeledData"];
In[23]:= Dimensions["C" /. mat]
Out[23]= {5, 4, 2, 3}
```

which shows that first two `Matlab` indices go to tail in the same order and remaining indices go from the beginning in reverse order.

Is this behaviour by design or by bug? Can I read somewhere about exact rules of index transposing during import?

I see no word about it [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MAT.html).

Comment: matlabs arrays are odd. Fundamentally there are only 1- and 2- d arrays, with the higher order arrays implemented as arrays of arrays. Matlab arrays are  fortran-like column major so the importer needs to do some  transposition.  That is to say there is some sense to what you see, but that doesn't make it right.

Comment: Maybe try hdf5 format? I've used python and octave to export complex high-dimensional matrices the let mathematica read in them without issue. matlab has a hdf5 write function https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdf5write.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal opinion is that this is a bug.

Our [MATLink](http://matlink.org/) package handles this well.

```
In[1]:= << MATLink`

In[2]:= OpenMATLAB[]

In[3]:= MEvaluate[
 "a=reshape(1:(3*4*5), [3,4,5]);
 size(a)"]

Out[3]= ">> 
ans =

     3     4     5

"

In[5]:= Dimensions@MGet["a"]

Out[5]= {3, 4, 5}
```

---

**Update:**

I looked at the implementation of the MAT5 file importer. It is written in pure Mathematica.  The relevant section is this:

[image]

It gives the impression that this is done quite deliberately.  Therefore I no longer think that it is a bug, but I do not know why it is done this way.

If you want to transfer data to/from MATLAB, and have both Mathematica and MATLAB installed on the same computer, I still recommend using MATLink.

Comment: It still can be a bug, as author could erroneously think that Matlab has a problem with first pair of indices.

Comment: @Dims Please contact Wolfram Support and let them know about this problem (then tell us what they said).

Comment: @Dims I think it does make sense in a way because MATLAB often presents 3D arrays (conceptually) as a "list of pages/slices" where each page is a matrix.  That's also how it displays them. The way Import handles the data conforms with that view: we get a list of *the same* matrices in Mathematica as we saw at the MATLAB command line.  Except that MATLAB uses the last index for the pages while Mathematica uses the first.

Comment: @Dims Of course once one starts looking at higher dimensional arrays, this does not generalize very well. That's why we did not make this choice in MATLink (but that was a long time ago and I forgot most of the discussions).   I guess the most intuitive index handling depends on the specific application. I prefer MATLink's.

Answer (score 2):

as a workaround use hdf5

```
A=reshape(1:(3*4*5),[3,4,5]);
h5create('xyz.hdf5','/A',[3,4,5])
h5write('xyz.hdf5','/A',A)
```

mathematica

```
a=Import["xyz.hdf5", "Data"][[1]]
```

this is fully reverse indexed..

```
Dimensions[a]
```

> {5,4,3}

reverse the index order to be matlab-like:

```
a = Transpose[a, Reverse@Range@ArrayDepth@a]];
Dimensions[a]
```

> {3,4,5}